# Request failed: forbidden (403) for fabric twitterkit

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to extract the members of a list using the TwitterKit API for iOS. As I understand, doing this will allow me to be "guest-authenticated" bypassing the need for my personal consumer and consumer-secret keys.

The code below attempts to get the members of a list using [this REST endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members)

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient()
let endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json"
let params = ["owner_screen_name" : "palafo", "slug" : "breakingnews"]
var clientError : NSError?

let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: endpoint, parameters: params, error: &clientError)

client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
   if connectionError != nil {
       print("Error: \(connectionError)")
   }

   do {
       let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
       print("json: \(json)")
   } catch let jsonError as NSError {
       print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

Running that gives me this error:

```
Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=220 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter API error : Your credentials do not allow access to this resource (code 220), TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=403, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?owner_screen_name=palafo&slug=breakingnews, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)})
```

If I change `endpoint` to instead get the statuses in that list using [this other REST endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/statuses), I get a proper JSON response.

```
let endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json"
```

Does this mean that Fabric's guest authentication does not allow me to get the members of a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved mine by using clientWithUserId instead of just initializing using just init.

```
NSString *userID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:userID];
```